# How could an old worm infect my computer on VMWare?

Tags: vmware, virus, anti-virus, malware

My current computer is on Windows 8.1, and using Norton. I've started to gain interest in old viruses, and therefor I've created an virtual machine using a software called VMWare (Workstation 11)

Anyways, I've looked into some worms and such to test it on Windows 98, but I don't really know if it could possibly infect my network, and/or computer?
The viruses are old, so I am pretty sure it would be detected by my firewall, but I would like someone to kinda clarify if it could infect me or not.

Comment: It could use an exploit that exists within how VMWare handles the virtual machine.  If you are worried setup dedecated hardware that isn't attached to the network.

Comment: Isolate the machine from the network anyway, and have up to date AV and malware-bytes installed and ready to go. Remove attached storage and then you should be set to go.

Comment: @Ramhound Concidering I'm testing old Windows 98 viruses and worms, I don't think it would exploit VM?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you leave the VM connected to the network, it could traverse the virtual network and infect other PCs.

Other than that, your attack surface is pretty minimal. I think, barring the virtual network, the real question is "can a virus in a VM essentially 'break out' of the VM and infect my PC"? And to that question my answer would be *maybe...*

I use VMs to run arbitrary code and protect my other PCs and servers from malicious code. So far, so good. However, about a year ago I ran across some code (trojan) that was *virtualization aware* - this sort of freaked me out a bit. I'm not sure if a virus could *break out* of the VM, but I believe it's possible. In theory, it could be aware that it is contained in a VM, and write itself to memory outside the VM containment. There are obvious issues with that, and it would be a very advanced technique - but not impossible.

If you're using only old viruses, you should be fine. I've been doing it for years.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

> The main reason a virus could propagate from VM to host Operating System is via the network. Once you start using bridged networking between the host and guest things get more risky. Your machine and the VM are seen as 2 nodes on the same subnet. A worm which sees these 2 nodes has the possibility of propagation if such a vulnerability is found.

It can't attack your system "through the WM" or anything like that. If you want to be totally safe just close the connection to the network!

Comment: I'm not using any briged connection or shared folders. Should I just disconnect my computer from the Internet?

Comment: Yes, that would probably the safest way of doing it. As far as I know this is the only way for the virus to break out. (And you should disconnect it also from other networks!)